# How to pass values to Angular from ASP.NET aspx page?

Tags: asp.net, .net, angular, webforms

I have used Angular build files in WebForms (`.aspx`) as JavaScript files.

I need to pass some values to Angular which are then used for other API calls.

Right now I'm using HTTP Cookies to pass the values. Is there any other way to pass values other than HttpCookie?

Comment: Hi and welcome Mohan! Please elaborate a bit on your reasoning. Are the cookies not good for a specific reason? Are there errors (if so, please post code and messages)? I can think of a number of ways, but not knowing anything about the underlying problems makes it difficult to give a precise answer.

Answer (score 0):

I see two other simple ways:

- set some initial value in a JavaScript variable with the settings
- create a "setup" API call, that returns the settings

Answer (score 0):

There are more ways to do this then there is flavors of ice-cream.

I really don't know angular much.

But, say this markup:

```
    <asp:HiddenField ID="hCustomer" runat="server" ClientIDMode="Static" />

    <div style="padding: 35px">

        <div ng-app="myApp" ng-controller="myCtrl">

            Full Name: {{firstName + " " + lastName}} <br />
            Company: {{Company}} <br />

        </div>

    </div>

    <script>

        var Customer = JSON.parse(document.getElementById("hCustomer").value)

        var app = angular.module('myApp', []);
        app.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {
            $scope.firstName = Customer.FirstName;
            $scope.lastName = Customer.LastName;
            $scope.Company = Customer.Company;
        });

    </script>
```

So, code behind to pass those values?

This works:

```
Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Not IsPostBack Then

        Dim MyCustomer As New Dictionary(Of String, String)

        MyCustomer.Add("FirstName", "Albert")
        MyCustomer.Add("LastName", "Kallal")
        MyCustomer.Add("Company", "Turtle Creek Tours")

        Dim JS As New JavaScriptSerializer
        hCustomer.Value = JS.Serialize(MyCustomer)

    End If

End Sub
```

And the result is now this:

[image]

I used a dictionary in place of creating a separate class, and they are kind of handy, since you can just "cook up" and write out code with as many variables you want to pass to the client side.